# MVC 3 - controller being called more than once

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am finding that my controllers are being called more than once. When I am in debug mode, the paths execute, the UI is rendered, but then the controller break points get hit up to 3 times.

Debugging steps so far:

- I have checked that all my routes (routedebugger.dll)
- I have a clean view to controller mapping. There are no namespace conflictions.

Is this something to do with the debugger, or is this an issue I need to worry about when the application is deployed?

Comment: are they the same action being called? could it be a favicon request?

Comment: In IE, press F12 -> Developer Tools -> network -> Start capturing -> submit request, you should see in the list how many requests are being sent to your server.

Comment: @ Daniel A. White: I checked Fiddler and there is a call to favicon. I wonder if that is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This symptom is only occurring on my local machine. I used fiddler2 to watch the traffic and there was a favicon call. I fixed that, but don't change anything.

We moved the code based to the servers (running iis) and this does not occur. I don't really have an answer, but do know that it is not affecting the production or QA servers.

I'm calling this one 'closed'.